# Why we need a unitName in the PersistenceContext injection in an EJB

Tags: openjpa, entitymanager

When I inject a PersistenceContext in an EJB like this:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "someEntity")
private EntityManager em = null;
```

What is the unitName=someEntity doing here? In my project i see these kind of declarations but i was hoping to find some xml file called someEntity.xml, but I cannot find it. There is a RAD project called someEntity but i dont see why we need to specify that as unitName.
Also, I am not able to appreciate why we cannot jsut do this:

```
@Autowired
private EntityManager em = null;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<persistence-unit name="someEntity">
```

That persistence unit should be defined in the META-INF/persistence.xml file.